# Lebesgue measure unbounded sets

Tags: lebesgue-measure

I have a question which asks if the following is true: if $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are closed, disjoint sets that are unbounded, then $m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(A)+m^*(B)$.
I think it is true due to the fact that $A$,$B$ are closed which implies they are Borel (so measurable). But then I don't see how the unbounded bit comes into the question. Am I missing a trick here? thank you.

edit: $m^*$ is the outer lebesgue measure.

Comment: Outer measure is not additive.

Comment: If the sets are closed disjoint and bounded then it is?

Comment: If you officially know that all Borel sets are Lebesgue measurable, and that the outer measure is additive on measurable sets, then you are done.